# Getting Cake's build.cake and asp.net core to work on travis-ci

Tags: asp.net-core, travis-ci, .net-core, cakebuild

What must I put in my `.travis.yml` to run cake.build and compile a .net core project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add [build.sh](http://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/setting-up-a-new-project) to your github repository, then give it execute rights,
in windows run the following command `git update-index --add --chmod=+x build.sh` while you are in the same directory as `build.sh`.

To just get cake.build to run add the following content:

```
language: csharp
script:
  - ./build.sh

cache:
  directories:
    - src/packages
    - tools
```

To install the `dotnet cli` add the following content:

```
language: csharp
os:
  - linux

sudo: required
dist: trusty
env:
  - CLI_VERSION=latest

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - gettext
    - libcurl4-openssl-dev
    - libicu-dev
    - libssl-dev
    - libunwind8
    - zlib1g

install:
  - export DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR="$PWD/.dotnetcli"
  - curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --version "$CLI_VERSION" --install-dir "$DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR"
  - export PATH="$DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR:$PATH"

script:
  - ./build.sh

cache:
  directories:
    - src/packages
    - tools
```

Comment: I used the following blogpost to get the information for `dotnet cli` http://andrewlock.net/adding-travis-ci-to-a-net-core-app/

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use MSFT instructions to install on Linux (with minor tweaks):

```
language: csharp

os:
  - linux
dist: trusty
sudo: required

before_install:
  - 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list'
  - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
  - sudo apt-get update -qq

install:
  - sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121

script:
  - ./build.sh

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.local/share/NuGet/Cache
    - tools
```

It needs sudo, but on the other hand you don't have to specify the dependencies.

In theory you can also make the above work using only the [APT addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon) but I don't know what to put on the `key_url`. Something like this on the `addons` section:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - sourceline: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main'
        key_url: ???
    packages:
      - dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

If we knew the GPG key url, this would be the most concise way.